# Lambda function is not triggered for all the s3 image upload

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have s3 bucket as below,

myBucket

- a/
- b/
- c/

where *myBucket* is a s3 bucket and a, b, c are the key folders inside that bucket.
I will upload images into *a/*. The s3 event notification will trigger SQS which will then trigger lambda function which does the process of removing image background and uploads into *b/* folder.

The problem here is for example, if I upload a folder which has around 26 images into s3 only 23 or 22 images are getting triggered by lambda and only those images are getting are processed.

For some reason s3 is not triggering all the images or is that something I should configure in my lambda function?

Here is my function code

```
exports.handler = async(event, context, callback) => {
  try {
    console.log(event.Records[0]);
    var json = JSON.parse(event.Records[0]['body']);
    console.log('json: '+json);
    json = JSON.parse(json['Message']);
    json = json['Records'][0]['s3'];
    console.log(json);

    var srcBucket = json['bucket']['name'];
    console.log('srcBucket: ' + srcBucket);
    var srcKey = decodeURIComponent(json['object']['key'].replace(/\+/g, ' '));
    console.log('srcKey: ' + srcKey);
    var str = (srcKey.split('/').pop()).split('.')[0];
    console.log('str: ' + str);

    if (str != '') {
      var folderPath = srcKey.substr(srcKey.indexOf('/') + 1).split('.')[0];
      folderPath = folderPath.substring(0, folderPath.lastIndexOf('/'));
      console.log('folderPath: ' + folderPath);

      const params1 = { Bucket: srcBucket, Key: srcKey };
      var origimage = await s3.getObject(params1).promise();
      var destObject = await origimage.Body;
      var destKey = 'removebg/' + folderPath + '/' + str + '.jpg';

      var options = {
        'method': 'POST',
        'url': 'https://api.remove.bg/v1.0/removebg',
        'headers': {
          'X-Api-Key': 'xxxxxxxxxxx'
        },
        formData: {
          'image_file': destObject,
          'size': 'auto'
        },
        encoding: null
      };

      request(options, function(error, response, body) {

        if (error) {
          console.log(error);
          sendmessage(error, 'Error removing image background', arn, srcBucket + '/' + srcKey, destBucket + destKey);
        }

        var params = { Bucket: destBucket, Key: destKey, Body: body };

        s3.upload(params, function(err, data) {
          if (err) {
            console.log('Error uploading data: ', err);
            sendmessage(err, 'Error uploading transparent image to s3', arn, srcBucket + '/' + srcKey, destBucket + destKey);

          }
          else { console.log('Successfully uploaded data to ' + destBucket); }
        });
      });
    }
  }
  catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
  callback(null, 'All done!');
};
```

Please let me know. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you check cloudwatch log of the Lambda function? It might tell something. I guess the function timed-out.

Comment: Is the bucket versioned?

Comment: Please Edit your question and show us your AWS Lambda function code. Specifically, do you loop through all of the `Records` provided in the `event`?

Comment: @shimo yes I did check the log function. I guess it is not time out issue

Comment: @Marcin I have not done the bucket versioning. Is it necessary?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Please find the function code. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem lies on these lines:

```
    console.log(event.Records[0]);
    var json = JSON.parse(event.Records[0]['body']);
    console.log('json: '+json);
    json = JSON.parse(json['Message']);
    json = json['Records'][0]['s3'];
```

Your function is only looking at the *first* record that is provided to the function. Multiple events can be given the the Lambda function, so **your function should loop through the `Records` entries** and process *all* of the events that are provided.

It should do something like:

```
  for record in event.Records:
    console.log(record);
    var json = JSON.parse(record['body']);
    console.log('json: '+json);
    json = JSON.parse(json['Message']);
    json = record['s3'];
```

Comment: Sorry for getting on this lately. Could you please tell me how do I loop? Because I am using SNS notification which will get notified when an image is uploaded to s3 folder which will in turn trigger SQS. This SQS will trigger lambda. So I believe SQS will have one record at a time. Isn't it?

Comment: I have added a code example. Try it and see if it works! Or, at a minimum, start logging `len(event.Records)` to verify whether multiple records are passed.

Comment: Thanks much @John . It worked. Alternatively we can also make the SQS batch size to 1 which is 10 by default.